# What were the forces imparted by the chicken gun?

Tags: flight-testing, nasa

How hard does the [chicken gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_gun) hit? Putting aside the apocryphal story of the British engineers who [forget to defrost the chicken](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/catapoultry/) before firing it, what is the peak force the average chicken imparts?

(Of course this is a function of speed and impact site, I'm just looking for a data point or two.)

Comment: Wikipedia says 270kts typically.

Comment: @JohnK, I saw that, but the peak forces will be a function of how compliant the chicken is and the wikipedia article doesn't cover that.

Answer (score 4):

According to the relevant rules (for example [14 CFR 25.571](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/25.571)):

> The airplane must be capable of successfully completing a flight during which likely structural damage occurs as a result of -
>
> 1. Impact with a 4-pound bird when the velocity of the airplane relative to the bird along the airplane's flight path is equal to Vc at sea level or 0.85Vc at 8,000 feet, whichever is more critical;

Note that in the calculation of the kinetic energy, the mass of the bird (4lb, 1.8kg) enters in the equation together with the designed cruising speed **of the airplane** Vc (and obviously not the bird's flying speed).

That value of kinetic energy should give you an idea of how piercing the impact can be. Translating the value of kinetic energy into a force is quite complicated since the force depends on the structural properties both of the bird and of the hit structure. That's why chicken guns are still in use despite the fancy simulation tools run during the design phase.

Just as example, this is how it looks like reality vs. simulation (all pictures from [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/325564967_Design_of_aircraft_structures_against_threat_of_bird_strikes)):

[image: bird strike, simulation Vs. test]

[image: bird strike, simulation Vs. test]

Getting a ballpark estimate of the impact forces might be done using an energy approach with some simplification; we suppose that:

- the airplane's structure deforms in a spring-like way; actually after the impact the structure remains deformed and it might even be broken, so it doesn't really behave like a spring;
- the impacting body does not disintegrate i.e. its kinetic energy is all transferred in deformation of the spring; this is also not perfectly true.

We have:

$E_\mathrm{k}=\frac12 mV^2=E_\mathrm{e}=\frac12 kx^2$

$F=kx$

Where $k$ is the *rigidity* of the spring, $x$ its deformation and $F$ the force needed to deform it.

Equating and extracting $F$ we get:

$F=\frac{mV^2}{x}$

Let's substitute some numbers:

- $m=1.8~\mathrm{kg}$
- $V=100~\mathrm{m/s}$
- $x=10~\mathrm{cm}=0.1~\mathrm{m}$

$F=180~\mathrm{kN}$

Comment: That's really interesting, but I need the force, not the pressure. (We're trying to determine the reaction forces on the wing/fuselage attachment anchors if a birdstrike on the wingtip occurs.) Through your answer, I found DTIC_ADA021142, which includes pressures vs distance, and therefore can integrate to get force. Any chance you could update your answer with data from that, so I can mark the answer as correct?

Comment: @KennSebesta: done.

Comment: Thinking of it as a spring is insightful. This works out to a 50000G deceleration, which leaves me awestruck, but that's the math. This makes me think that the chicken-gun test is inadequate to answer my question for the airplane design, since considering these astronomical forces it's much more likely that the LE of the wing will cleave the bird in two.

Comment: My next SE.Aviation question: "how much force does it take to chop a bird in half with a NACA 4-digit airfoil?"

Answer (score 0):

Rewatched the MythBusters episode to get their speeds and data.  Now, it's time to do some math.

$m = \frac{4~\mathrm{lb}}{32.174~\mathrm{ft/s}^2} = 0.124~\mathrm{slug}$

$V = 140~\frac{\mathrm{mi}}{\mathrm{h}} = 205.3~\frac{\mathrm{ft}}{\mathrm{s}}$

$t = 0.007~\mathrm{s}$

In both cases, $a = V1/t = 29333~\mathrm{ft/s}^2$

Since $F_\mathrm{avg} = ma$, $F_\mathrm{avg} = 0.124~\mathrm{slug} \cdot 29333~\mathrm{ft/s}^2 = 3647~\mathrm{lb}$

Separately, if we consider the numbers in the wikipedia article you posted, $V = 350~\mathrm{mi/h} = 513~\mathrm{ft/s}$. If we assume the same rate of energy dissipation as the MythBusters test and a 4lb chicken, then:

$k_\mathrm{MB} = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 = \frac{1}{2}(0.124~\mathrm{slug}) \cdot (205.3~\mathrm{ft/s})^2 = 2613~\mathrm{ft}\cdot\mathrm{lb}$

$\frac{k_\mathrm{MB}}{t_\mathrm{MB}} = \frac{2613~\mathrm{ft}\cdot\mathrm{lb}}{0.007~\mathrm{s}} = 373,311~\mathrm{ft}\cdot\mathrm{lb/s}$

$k_\mathrm{wiki} = \frac{1}{2}(0.124~\mathrm{slug})(513~\mathrm{ft/s})^2 = 16316~\mathrm{ft}\cdot\mathrm{lb}$

$t_\mathrm{wiki} = \frac{k_\mathrm{wiki}}{\frac{k_\mathrm{MB}}{t_\mathrm{MB}}} = \frac{16316~\mathrm{ft}\cdot\mathrm{lb}}{373311~\mathrm{ft}\cdot\mathrm{lb/s}} = 0.043~\mathrm{s}$

Then, $a = V/t = \frac{513~\mathrm{ft/s}}{0.043~\mathrm{s}} = 11737~\mathrm{ft/s}^2$

and $F = ma = 0.124~\mathrm{slug} \cdot 11737~\mathrm{ft/s}^2 = 1455~\mathrm{lb}$

If instead we assume the deceleration time is constant:

$a_\mathrm{wiki} = \frac{513~\mathrm{ft/s}}{0.007~\mathrm{s}} = 73285~\mathrm{ft/s}^2$

$F_\mathrm{wiki} = 0.124~\mathrm{slug} \cdot 73285~\mathrm{ft/s}^2 = 9087~\mathrm{lb}$

And interestingly enough, based on the MythBusters' testing, a frozen and thawed chicken would impart the same force.

Comment: Re last sentence-- how could that be true?  Any way to explain a bit to give some insight on how that could be true?  Is the idea that with the frozen bird, the windshield shatters before the before the full force can be applied, somehow somewhat akin to the advantage of a bullet that "mushrooms" quickly rather than maintains original pointed shape for longer?  Just grasping at straws here, and curious, feel free to ignore, or respond/edit, as you see fit--

Comment: _Force_ is a tricky metric when evaluating collisions. Assuming the entire chicken is eventually "absorbed" by the aircraft (all pieces of the chicken eventually come to rest in the aircraft's inertial reference frame), the total energy (mv^2/2) and momentum (mv) transferred are equal, since m and v are equal. But force is _not_. The thawed chicken deforms on impact, dramatically increasing the collision times and correspondingly decreasing the, let's say very casually, "average" instantaneous forces. Some energy is also dissipated internally via deformation heating, unlike the frozen chicken.

Comment: In this case, the force calculation results from the impact time (as we are calculating average force).  In the MythBusters test (S2E10), both chickens stopped against the steel plate in 0.007s from the same speed.  This would mean that the force applied by the plate to stop the chicken (and thus the force imparted by the chicken - Newton's 3rd law) would be the same for each test.

Comment: I haven't seen the MythBusters episode, but in general **MythBusters did incredibly poor science**. It was entertainment, not science (and I quite liked the show). Another factor to consider is the _area_ over which force is applied: the thawed and deforming chicken will spread out the applied force over a larger area than the frozen one. That factor may be more important than the duration of impact.

Comment: @TypeIA You're now invoking pressure.  We can't calculate pressure without more information and data of our own.  Failure is a function of stress, which shares units with pressure, and the peak stresses will be lower in if the load is distributed over a larger area.  At the same time, the *force* applied by the chicken will still be the same for a given mass and acceleration, even if the area is different.  I also did my own math based on their data instead of just trusting specifically because it eliminates everything but their raw data, which is no different than googling

Comment: In the first 2 "Chicken Cannon" episodes, the Myth Busters ***massively*** missed the mark. The *third* episode with the layers of glass panes, they got it right. Shooting into an iron plate doesn't model a bird hitting a windshield well at all... a 4-pound water balloon dropped on you from 6 feet would hurt a little (and soak your clothes), while a 4-pound block of ice dropped from that height would cause real damage. Same deal with thawed vs frozen chickens.

Comment: @FlyJunior172: thanks for doing this. Could we ask for it to be done in metric, so a wider audience can review the math, and not trip up on `lbf` vs `lbm` problems?